# Get live screenshot of window in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to find a way to get a live view of a specific window. In the same way that Mission Control and Exposé will show you live views of windows that are currently obscured by other windows (this  is also done by Hyperdock, so I'm pretty certain that its not a private API).

What is the functionality called? And so where is the documentation on it?

Answer (score 1):

You want the [Quartz Window Services API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/carbon/reference/cgwindow_reference/Reference/Introduction.html). Basically, you want to create a window list with the windows you're interested in and use CGWindowListCreateImage to get a picture of the window's contents.

Comment: The image will be static, however, not live, so you'll have to poll it or do some trickery with screen-update callbacks (if a portion of the window that is visible visibly changes, re-capture the whole window).

Comment: @Jonathan.: If you mean being notified whenever something is drawn in a window, I'm not aware of one. HyperDock doesn't do that either. You can get screen update callbacks from Quartz Display Services, but AFAIK that won't catch if hidden parts of a window are redrawn.

Comment: @Chuck or is there an API to get a kind of stream or something? Is it known how Apple do it mission control?

Comment: @Jonathan.: Mission Control is implemented by the Dock, which has deep ties into the windowserver and can basically do whatever it wants with your windows. Last I checked, it was possible for an app to do unsupported black magic and gain similar control, but those are some uncharted waters.